# Maximum width of screen in the QGIS modelbuilder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I am trying to make a model in the QGIS modelbuilder. The problem I am encountering is that my model is getting fairly wide. I have a lot more to put in under the base that is have now. The problem is that when I zoom further in, a lot of parts in the model are unreachable because the screen won't move any further then a certain point.
I looked in the settings, but I couldn't find a option or clarification about the width of the model itself.

[image]
This is how far I can zoom in before the outer parts become unreachable.

Does somebody here know if there is a limit to how big your model can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it out in the modeller pane and checked all the settings and it seems that, yes, there is functionally a limit to the (graphical) extent of your model. I've run through the source code (insofar as I understand it) and I can't obviously see where this is set, but I suspect if you want to change it you'll have to modify the source code and customise the modeller, which would be a lot of effort.

Since you can zoom out to a wider canvas than you can navigate while zoomed in, I would suggest that a more accessible solution is to keep the bottom half of the canvas as a "construction zone" where you build your model, then zoom out, select the relevant parts, and drag them to somewhere that they're more structurally intuitive. AFAIK this should still let you export visual representations (PDF, JPG) of the model without loss of quality, but I haven't tested this.

An alternative and slightly more technical possible solution is to build your model in stages and save each stage as an algorithm. So if, for example, it breaks into three logical sections, you can construct those sections individually, *Export > Export as Python Script*, then go to *Processing > Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Create New Script*, and load and save your previously exported script. Once there, it will be accessible under the Algorithms tab in the Graphical Modeller under the (new, if it's your first script) *Scripts* tab. This way each part of your model will only take up one "box" of space - BUT to edit each of those parts you will need to edit the original model and re-import the script.

Neither of these is a perfect solution, but hopefully they give you a workaround :)

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer. But thank you for your efforts to answer my question with such clarity. I will find a way to work it out, thanks again!